# how do I tell Composer to store sources elsewhere?

Tags: composer-php

I am using Composer and I'm on OS X.

It's putting the git clones for required packages in ~/.composer/vendor/.

Some of these libraries are source code I may want to work with, make patches or pull requests, and so having these hidden away in a .folder is a pain.

How can I get Composer to put these somewhere else?

Ideally, I'd like that on a case by case basis, but I could live with them being somewhere more OS X-ish, such as ~/Library/Application\ Support/Composer for example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have discovered the cache. You shouldn't care about it's location or content. That's why it is hidden.

If you run Composer with "--prefer-source", it will clone the repositories needed into the vendor folder of your application. There you can work with them if you feel the need.

Comment: I don't have an application per se, AFAIK. I used Composer to install Drush (PHP command line tool for Drupal), and it put the source for that and its dependencies in .composer.

Comment: Then you ran something like `composer global require ...`, and this is expected to install the stuff in this particular location. You are supposed to add the `~/.composer/vendor/bin` path to your PATH environment variable to make full use of installed binaries/scripts there (the ~ probably should be resolved to the full path). If you want to work on a project, you should clone it into a sufficient working directory and then start editing, committing and pushing.

Comment: "this is expected to install the stuff in this particular location" -- so it would seem. My question is how do I customize this location?